# Unable to read object variable in ssis

Tags: ssis

Need some help guys. I recently came across this problem while developing a package for my client.
I am saving the result set of the SQl task in a user variable (object) and then trying to access it in various script tasks. The scope of the variable is set to package level. When I use the below code, I am able to retrieve the value of it in Script task of S.Container , but if I use the same code in Script task of S.Container2, I am unable to. in the later, the 'dt' just shows the headers , not the data.

Any reason for this particular behavior.? What is am i missing ?

SQL Task code -----------

```
select * from dimproduct
```

Script task code -----------

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 DataRow row = null;
 OleDbDataAdapter oleDA = new OleDbDataAdapter();
 oleDA.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["Variable"].Value);
    foreach (DataRow row_ in dt.Rows)
     {
       row = row_;
     }
```

[image]

EDIT :: The following code also doesn't work.

```
Variables lockedVariables = null;
            Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::Variable");
            Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables( ref lockedVariables);
            object A;
             A= lockedVariables["User::Variable"].Value;
            lockedVariables.Unlock();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow row = null;
            OleDbDataAdapter oleDA = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            oleDA.Fill(dt, A);
            foreach (DataRow row_ in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = row_;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you haven't accidentally declared the variable twice, once with the scope of the package, and once with the scope of the first sequence container?

Edit: Calling Fill seems to clear the source results, as this should demonstrate:

```
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    OleDbDataAdapter oleDA = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    oleDA.Fill(dt1, Dts.Variables["Results"].Value);
    foreach (DataRow row_ in dt1.Rows)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(row_[0].ToString());
    }

    //Try and fill with the same data adapter
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
    oleDA.Fill(dt2, Dts.Variables["Results"].Value); 
    foreach (DataRow row_ in dt2.Rows)
    {
        //This will never be hit
        MessageBox.Show(row_[0].ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Yes I am. It's just one variable. Could you please try it yourself.

Comment: @Akshay, OK I tried it, I get the same results as you. It looks like calling the Fill empties the source data adapter. I'd assign the datatable you fill to a new object variable?

Comment: 1 thing i am not able to understand why just the headers populate and not the data. 1 more thing i tried,  copied the execute SQL task to S.Container2 and then everything ran fine.It's a starnge behavior of the tool.

Comment: @Akshay, no it's not the tool, its that calling fill empties the rows. The metadata is still there, which is why you get column names but no rows. Try my example I have edited in above.

Comment: But it's just the adapter. The variable value should still hold the data isn't it ? I have tried by accessing variabldispenser as well , unlocking it, but in vain. I am going nuts over this problem now.

Comment: So put the data in a datatable and assign that to a variable so you can reuse it. Or raise it as a bug with Microsoft Connect. SSIS does have a lot of "gotcha" things you'll run into, just work around it and move on.

Comment: I get you. It's probably a bug.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug reported to microsoft about it ..

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/265841/ssis-cannot-clone-a-recordset-built-using-the-recordset-destination

Though i stii feel Recordsets are generally single-use collections. When you call that Fill method, it walks forward through the recordset and copies the data into the DataTable until the recordset is consumed.